# SQL Server 2008 error

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have this code

```
Dim str As String

Dim myConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Server=JDBRANDE;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False")

Dim myCommand As SqlCommand

Try
   myConn.Open()
   str = "insert into orders_table(tuid,customer_tuid,start_time,finish_time ) " + " VALUES ('2342', '455', 'NULL', 'NULL')"
   'MsgBox(str)

   myCommand = New SqlCommand(str, myConn)
   myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I keep getting an invalid object name `orders_table` error

When I go directly to SQL Server and type in the insert statement, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You connection string is either pointing to a database different from the one your manually referring to, one that does not have that table, and/or you've got the name wrong in the sql statement.

Edit - Hmm what the other answers say about missing the schema/initial catalog is most likely your problem.

Comment: Thank you... i forgot to include the database name in the connection string

Comment: @User thanks but I think one of the other two answers was more complete and correct then mine.

Answer (score 2):

You have not set the database name on the connection string..

```
Dim myConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Server=JDBRANDE;Database=DBNameIntegrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False")
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check that `JDBRANDE` is definitely the correct server.

If it is, try changing your query to specify a table name:

```
INSERT INTO my_database.orders_table(tuid,customer_tuid,start_time,finish_time )...
```

Alternatively, try specifying an `Initial Catalog` in the connection string.

**EDIT :** Example of connection using `Initial Catalog` (from [http://www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008))

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

Comment: JDBRANDE is the correct server.. I tried the myDatabase.orders_table and the error changed to "Invalid object name myDatabase.orders_table"

Also, would you mind showing what you mean by the Initial Catalog

Comment: It's a way of specifying the default database context within the connection string. See my edit for an example